How to set column width in Tasks environment
By default, the tasks environment seems to divide the available horizontal space equally among the specified columns.  For short tasks, this can lead to overly wide column widths:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}

\noindent
Some preceding text.

\begin{tasks}(2)
  \task Task 1
  \task Task 2
  \task Task 3
  \task Task 4
\end{tasks}

\end{document}


This graphic from the Tasks manual suggests there is an internal length called item width, but there does not appear to be a corresponding key:

Is there a way to set the column widths?

You can put the whole tasks environment into a minipage

@Stephen Brilliance in simplicity.  I can't wait to get back to my computer to experiment with this.  Thanks!

@Stephen or anyone!  The good news is that the minipage wrap has the desired effect.  The bad news is that this seems to render the task keys (like before-skip) inoperable.  I've tried inserting newline, linebreak, and par immediately after minipage to no avail.  Any suggestions?

\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}\leavevmode

At the beginning of minipage, TeX is in vertical mode so vertical skip has no effect here. One has to leave vertical mode first:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{before-skip = {1cm}}
\begin{document}

\noindent
Some preceding text.


\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}\leavevmode
  \begin{tasks}(2)
    \task Task 1
    \task Task 2
    \task Task 3
    \task Task 4
  \end{tasks}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}



Literally hundreds of my worksheets will inherit and benefit from your suggestions here.  Thank you very much.

An alternative to the task package using the new enumext package:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumext}
\setenumext[enumext*]{label=\alph*),topsep=10pt,columns=2,columns-sep=5pt}
\begin{document}

\noindent
Some preceding text.

\begin{enumext*}
  \item Item 1
  \item Item 2
  \item Item 3
  \item Item 4
\end{enumext*}

\end{document}


The syntax for the keys is similar to that for the enumitem and tasks packages, it is recommended to read the documentation.

Does enumext have a key for column widths?

The interface provided does not have that utility, the \itemwidth dimension is set after applying the calculations for the horizontal and inter-column spaces. You can see the calculation itself in the implementation part of the package.

So you're not proposing this package as a solution to my question then?

Indeed yes, but there are several considerations to take into account, the enumext* environment supports \item(join) so the column width is relative, you must also take into consideration the list-offset key along with right margin.

Would you mind updating your provided example to demonstrate how the column widths can be reduced with these parameters?
